# Getting model name in Django template

Tags: python, django

I am trying to do a search over many data models in Django to my site.
Now I have code like this in views.

```
class Search(ListView):
    template_name="search.html"
    context_object_name="result_serch_all"
    paginate_by = 10

    def get_queryset(self):
        news = Articles.objects.filter(title__icontains=self.request.GET.get("q"))
        docs = Doc.objects.filter(name_doc__icontains=self.request.GET.get("q"))
        query_sets = list(chain(news, docs))
        return query_sets

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        paginator = Paginator(self.get_queryset(), 5)
        context = super().get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        context["q"] =f'q={self.request.GET.get("q")}&'
        print(context['result_serch_all'])
        return context
```

In the template, I output like this

```
   {%for el in result_serch_all%}
       <div> {{el}} </div>
   {% endfor %}
```

How can the output in the template be divided into blocks?So that in front of all found articles there is an inscription `Found in the news section`. Before the documents Found in the documents section`?

I found this option. In my model im add

```
def get_my_model_name(self):
    return self._meta.model_name
```

and in the template I check

```
{% if el.get_my_model_name == 'articles' %}
```

Maybe there is some standard way in Django?

Comment: Having the method like this is fine. But if you are separating the search results by model in the template, why do you mix them together in the view in the first place? Also, a model with a plural name is misnomered 99% of the time.

Comment: @schwobaseggl so that pagination displays 10 found values ​​per page.I could not make pagination if I add search results separately to the context

Comment: Makes sense. I don't see a better way to access the model name (which should be `Article` really) in the template. Also, with the default set of context processors, you can access the query in the template via `{{ request.GET.q }}`